# slideshow looping randomly and sometimes skips very fast

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow, jsfiddle

I'm trying to make a slideshow but it isnt looping like it will be. It looping like 1-2-1-3-2-2 and sometimes it skips.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/296vLj3z/

HTML:

```
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <a class="btn" href="/mangalar/manga1"><img class="bannerimg" src="https://wallpapers.com/images/hd/jojo-bizarre-adventure-hero-banners-97au0jin9lw0i6lz.webp"/></a>
    <div class="text btn" onclick="window.location.href='/mangalar/manga1'">Manga1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <a class="btn" href="/mangalar/manga2"><img class="bannerimg" src="https://wallpapers.com/images/hd/jojo-bizarre-adventure-hero-banners-97au0jin9lw0i6lz.webp"/></a>
    <div class="text btn" onclick="window.location.href='/mangalar/manga2'">Manga2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <a class="btn" href="/mangalar/manga3"><img class="bannerimg" src="https://wallpapers.com/images/hd/jojo-bizarre-adventure-hero-banners-97au0jin9lw0i6lz.webp"/></a>
    <div class="text btn" onclick="window.location.href='/mangalar/manga3'">Manga3</div>
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
  <a class="next" id="nextSlide" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
let slideIndex = 1; showSlides(slideIndex); function plusSlides(n) { showSlides((slideIndex += n)); } function currentSlide(n) { showSlides((slideIndex = n)); } function showSlides(n) { let i; let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides"); let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot"); if (n > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1; } if (n < 1) { slideIndex = slides.length; } for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) { slides[i].style.display = "none"; } for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) { dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", ""); } slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block"; dots[slideIndex - 1]; setInterval(function(){document.getElementById('nextSlide').click();}, 5000);}
```

The loop function is this:

```
setInterval(function(){document.getElementById('nextSlide').click();}, 5000);}
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) and click TIDY before saving.

Comment: Every time you click something that executes showSlides, you execute `setInterval` So have in the top: `let tId;` and then use `clearInterval(tId); tId = setInterval(function() { ...... })`